# Is there a Linux equivalent to Windows >log.txt for logging command output to a file?

Tags: linux, logging

The character > (or >>) can be used with a command in Windows to log results of a command to file. Does Linux have this ability? How do you do it?

Example:
$ find /?>find.txt

This command will make a file named find.txt in the current directory. This file will contain exactly what is found in the term window after typing the command:

```
Searches for a text string in a file or files.

FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
  /C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
  /N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
  /I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  "string"   Specifies the text string to find.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
```

Comment: One interesting feature is the null feature. On Windows: `echo "hello world" > NUL` and on Linux: `echo "hello world" > /dev/null`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works the same way in Linux.  `>` will overwrite the output file, `>>` will append to it.  Some programs will print errors to STDERR, which you can capture using `2>`.  Sometimes you will see STDERR redirected to the same location as STDOUT using `2>&1`, so that all output can be captured at once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can redirect output from a command using `>` or `>>` in the shell on Linux as well. See the section on [redirection](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07) in your shell documentation (link goes to the POSIX standard, other shells may support more advanced types of redirection).

```
echo "This is a test" > file.txt
```

If you want to print output to both a file and the terminal, you can use [`tee`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tee.html):

```
echo "This is a test" | tee file.txt
```

Note that given the document you link to, [`grep`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/grep.html) is probably the closest equivalent to the `find` command listed. [`find`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) on Linux/Unix will recursively search for files with names or other metadata matching conditions given; `grep` will search through a single file for lines matching a given pattern.

Comment: your redirection link is helpful, thanks! If I could give you a vote, I would. Alas, my reputation is only 9 and I have to have 15 before being able to vote.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it looks the same:

```
find --help > find.txt  # write to a new file
find --help >> find.txt # append to the file
```

Answer (score 0):

It work the same.

```
find / > log.txt
```

A extra bonus could be found with the tee command, 
this will save to a file and show the output the same time.

```
find / | tee log.txt
```